# Update with HQL error

Tags: sql-update, hql

Hi all i have the following code:

```
tx = session.beginTransaction();
        Query query = session.createQuery("UPDATE com.nisid.entities.Payment set  amount=:amount,paymentMethod=:method,paymentExpire=:expireDate"
                + "Where paymentId=:payid,actionId=:actionid");
        query.setParameter("amount", amount);
        query.setParameter("method", method);
        query.setParameter("expireDate", expireDate);
        query.setParameter("payid", projectId);
        query.setParameter("actionid", actionId);
        int resutl=query.executeUpdate();
```

Trying to do an update using HQL but i am getting error: galArgumentException: node to traverse cannot be null!

my table in the DB is called Payment and it has A COMPOSITE KEY ( projectId,actionId)
Could you please help me further???

The concept is that i have a JSP page which retrieves and displayes the results from DB retrieving info from Project Table, Payment Table  and Action Table. Project has many to many relationship with Action and i am using Payment Table as the intermetiary table which holds the 2 FK of the other table.

Answer (score 0):

You missed space before `where`, and replace `,` to `and` after `where`.

```
Query query = session.createQuery("UPDATE com.nisid.entities.Payment set  amount=:amount,paymentMethod=:method,paymentExpire=:expireDate"
                + " Where paymentId=:payid and actionId=:actionid");
```

Comment: hi i am now getting the following error: SEVERE: IllegalArgumentException in class: com.nisid.entities.PaymentID, getter method of property: myproject
SEVERE: org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: IllegalArgumentException occurred calling getter of com.nisid.entities.PaymentID.myproject

Comment: my purpose is to update 3 tables ( Payment table ,project table and action table ) 
i have a many to many relationship with Project table and Action table and i am using Payment table as the intermediatary table. is it possible to do the update as described above?

Comment: Do you have getters and setters in your object? Can you post this code (especially for com.nisid.entities.PaymentID.myproject)?